# Pattern for 'routing' events through several subscribers?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a group of classes with the following interface:

```
public interface RoutedEventReceiver<T>
{
    IDisposable Apply(IObservable<T> stream);
    bool ShouldForwardEvent(T anEvent);
}
```

What I would like to do is to maintain a stack of these classes, with each event being filtered through the `ShouldForwardEvent(T)` predicate, and the resulting `IObservable<T>` passed to the next receiver. I also want to be able to push and pop new receivers while my program is running (at some point I may want to move from a stack to some other collection but for now a stack is sufficient).

What I have currently does work, but I don't feel like it is very "Rx". I am sure there must be a way to do what I want without all this imperative logic:

```
private void Refresh()
{
    // _subscriptions is a list of previous subscriptions
    foreach (var subscription in _subscriptions)
        subscription.Dispose();
    _subscriptions.Clear();

    // _stream is my stream of incoming events
    if (_stream != null)
    {
        var stream = _stream;

        foreach (var eventReceiver in _eventReceivers)
        {
            // add the subscription so it can be disposed next Refresh()
            _subscriptions.Add(eventReceiver.Apply(stream));

            // filter the stream for the next event receiver
            stream = stream.Where(eventReceiver.ShouldForwardEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

The above method is called whenever I `Push` or `Pop` on the stack.

Is there a cleaner, more functional way to express the above intent? I have tried `.Publish()` but with little success - perhaps I don't know it well enough.

Comment: I find your interface inconsistent: you're working both with `IObservable<T>` and `T` directly. Wouldn't it make more sense to have something like `void Process(T anEvent)` instead of your `Apply()`?

Comment: Not in my case. The receiver must have the ability to use Rx operators on the event stream. I could change the `ShouldForwardEvent` method to take and return an `IObservable<T>` with the implicit contract that the source stream should be returned - but I don't like the implicit contract (and have no need for the extra functionality when a simple `Where` suffices)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make the `Publish` approach work, but it doesn't afford me much other than getting rid of the need to keep a list of `IDisposables`:

```
private void Refresh()
{
    _published.DisposeIfNotNull();

    if (_stream != null)
    {
        var connectable = _stream.Publish();
        _published = connectable.Connect();
        var stream = connectable.AsObservable();

        foreach (var eventReceiver in _eventReceivers)
        {
            eventReceiver.Apply(stream);
            stream = stream.Where(eventReceiver.ShouldForwardEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class below (named CORStack for Chain Of Responsibility* Stack), tries to do what you're after. Internally it adds an ShouldHandle bool to the stream and uses this to determine whether to process. It exposes the standard `Push`, `Pop`, and `Peek` methods.

```
public sealed class CORStack<T>
{
    Stack<StackFrame> _handlers;

    public CORStack(IObservable<T> source)
    {
        _handlers = new Stack<StackFrame>();
        _handlers.Push(new StackFrame(
            source.Select(t => new ShouldHandleWrapper(t, true)),
            new Handler<T>(new Action<T>(t => { }), true)));
    }

    public void Push(Handler<T> handler)
    {
        _handlers.Push(new StackFrame(_handlers.Peek().Observable, handler));
    }

    public Handler<T> Peek()
    {
        return _handlers.Peek().Handler;
    }

    public Handler<T> Pop()
    {
        var frame = _handlers.Pop();
        frame.Dispose();
        return frame.Handler;
    }

    class StackFrame : IDisposable
    {
        IDisposable _unsub;

        public IObservable<ShouldHandleWrapper> Observable { get; private set; }
        public Handler<T> Handler { get; private set; }

        public StackFrame(IObservable<ShouldHandleWrapper> topOfStack, Handler<T> handler)
        {
            _unsub = topOfStack.Subscribe(shouldHandle =>
                {
                    if (shouldHandle.ShouldHandle)
                        handler.Action.Invoke(shouldHandle.Value);
                });
            Observable = topOfStack.Select(shouldHandle =>
                new ShouldHandleWrapper(shouldHandle.Value, shouldHandle.ShouldHandle && handler.Forward));
            Handler = handler;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _unsub.Dispose();
        }
    }

    class ShouldHandleWrapper
    {
        public readonly T Value;
        public readonly bool ShouldHandle;

        public ShouldHandleWrapper(T value, bool shouldHandle)
        {
            Value = value;
            ShouldHandle = shouldHandle;
        }
    }
}

public class Handler<T>
{
    public Action<T> Action { get; set; }
    public bool Forward { get; set; }

    public Handler(Action<T> action, bool forward)
    {
        Action = action;
        Forward = forward;
    }
}
```

*I realised that it's not a chain of responsibility, but can't think of a better name atm.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I should have clarified - the *newest* member of the stack (or the topmost) should be the first one to receive the stream. This is why currently I need the `Refresh()` method - because when a new event receiver is added, the stream going to the top member of the stack has to change

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where I'd actually use `Subjects`.  Create a subject for each handler, then subscribe to the stream and loop through the handlers passing the event as required.  This avoids continually unsubscribing/resubscribing to the stream (and thus the `Refresh` method), which is not always appropriate.  We use `lock` to guard against a new receiver being added or removed at the same moment as a new value is coming through the stream.  If you can guarantee that cannot happen, then you can remove the `lock` statements.

```
public class YourClass<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Stack<Tuple<Subject<T>, RoutedEventReceiver<T>, IDisposable> _handlers;
    private readonly IObservable<T> _stream;
    private readonly IDisposable _streamSubscription;

    public YourClass(IObservable<T> stream)
    {
        _handlers = new Stack<Tuple<Subject<T>, RoutedEventReceiver<T>, IDisposable>();
        _stream = stream;
        _streamSubscription = stream.Subscribe(OnNext, OnError, OnCompleted);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _streamSubscription.Dispose();

        lock (_handlers)
        {
            foreach (var h in _handlers)
            {
                h.Item3.Dispose();
                h.Item1.Dispose();
            }
            _handlers.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void OnNext(T value)
    {
        lock (_handlers)
        {
            for (var h in _handlers)
            {
                h.Item1.OnNext(value);
                if (!h.Item2.ShouldForwardEvent(value)) break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnError(Exception e)
    {
        lock (_handlers)
        {
            for (var h in _handlers) { h.Item1.OnError(e); }
        }
    }

    private void OnCompleted()
    {
        lock (_handlers)
        {
            for (var h in _handlers) { h.Item1.OnCompleted(); }
        }
    }

    public void Push(RoutedEventReceiver<T> handler)
    {
        lock (_handlers)
        {
            var subject = new Subject<T>;
            _handlers.Push(Tuple.Create(subject, handler, handler.Apply(subject)));
        }
    }

    public RoutedEventReceiver<T> Pop()
    {
        lock (_handlers)
        {
            var handler = _handlers.Pop();
            handler.Item3.Dispose();
            handler.Item1.Dispose();
            return handler.Item2;
        }
    }
}
```